# Cannot start AEM as a service on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: shell, ubuntu, aem

I'm trying to setup AEM (Adobe Experience Manager) Author as a Service on Ubuntu 18.04 on an AWS EC2 instance.

Script file "aem" at `/usr/bin/aem` (file permissions to "root")

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# description: This service manages the Adobe Experience Manager java process.
# processname: aem6
. /lib/lsb/init-functions
SCRIPT_NAME=`basename $0`
AEM_ROOT=/opt/aem/author
AEM_USER=root

########
BIN=${AEM_ROOT}/crx-quickstart/bin
START=${BIN}/start
STOP=${BIN}/stop
STATUS=${BIN}/status

case "$1" in
  start)
    if [ -f $START ]; then
       echo "Starting AEM Service.."
       /bin/su -l $AEM_USER -c $START
       RETVAL=$?
       [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch /var/lock/subsys/${SCRIPT_NAME}
    fi
   ;;
   stop)
    if [ -f $STOP ]; then
       echo "Stopping AEM Service.."
       /bin/su -l $AEM_USER -c $STOP
       RETVAL=$?
       [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && rm -f /var/lock/subsys/${SCRIPT_NAME}
    fi
    ;;
    status)
      if [ -f $STATUS ]; then
         echo -s "Checking status of $SCRIPT_NAME: "
         /bin/su -l $AEM_USER -c $STATUS
         RETVAL=$?
         [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && echo "$SCRIPT_NAME is running"
      fi
   ;;
   restart)
      /bin/su -l ${AEM_USER} -c ${STOP}
      /bin/su -l ${AEM_USER} -c ${START}
   ;;
   reload)
   ;;
   *)
     echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|reload}"
     RETVAL=1
     ;;
esac
exit $RETVAL
```

Service file at `/etc/systemd/system/aem.service` (file permissions to "root")

```
[Unit]
Description=Adobe Experience Manager

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/aem start
ExecStop=/usr/bin/aem stop
ExecReload=/usr/bin/aem restart
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

when checking the service status:

```
ubuntu@ip-109:~$ sudo systemctl status aem 
aem.service - Adobe Experience Manager
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/aem.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (exited) since Wed 2019-10-23 20:25:21 UTC; 3min 24s ago
Process: 20106 ExecStart=/usr/bin/aem start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 20106 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 23 20:25:21 ip-172-31-14-109 systemd[1]: Started Adobe Experience Manager.
Oct 23 20:25:21 ip-172-31-14-109 aem[20106]: Starting AEM Service..
Oct 23 20:25:21 ip-172-31-14-109 su[20122]: Successful su for root by root
Oct 23 20:25:21 ip-172-31-14-109 su[20122]: + ??? root:root
Oct 23 20:25:21 ip-172-31-14-109 su[20122]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Oct 23 20:25:21 ip-172-31-14-109 aem[20106]: mesg: ttyname failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Oct 23 20:25:21 ip-172-31-14-109 su[20122]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user root
```

But cannot see "java" process (using `ps -ef | grep java` ) or port "4502" being used (using `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN`).

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

Was able to resolve the issue. The problem was with "java" not being available to all users. Installed Oracle Java using default (ubuntu) user, while the `aem` script was running as `root`.

Steps to install custom Java.. not the Ubuntu default:

- Download the `tar.gz` file "https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/8u231-b11/5b13a193868b4bf28bcb45c792fce896/jdk-8u 231-linux-x64.tar.gz"
- Copy the file to the server using SCP
- Make a directory `mkdir /opt/java`
- Install and copy `sudo tar -zxf jdk-8u231-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt/java/`
- Update your environment to allow Java for all users. Run this command

  - `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_231/bin/java 1`
- Add path to ".bashrc". Open to edit `sudo nano ~/.bashrc`

  - Add these lines to the end of the file:

    - `export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_231`
    - `export PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin`

After this.. start the "aem" service again. It should be working!